# Reading from a Database in an iPhone app

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, xcode, sqlite

Below is my code for reading from a database:

```
if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    const char *query_stmt = "SELECT QuestionID, question, RightAnswer,WrongAnswer1, WrongAnswer2, audio FROM questions WHERE done='no' AND Catagory='%@'", Catagory;

    int check = (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL));
    NSLog(@"%i",check);


    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {

        while(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            questionID = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
            questionString = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
            rightAnswerString = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];
            wrong1AnswerString = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3)];
            wrong2AnswerString = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 4)];
            audioInteger = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 5)];
            break;
        }

        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }
    sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

I want to read in the first row of my table where `done='no'` and the category matches the category stored in the variable catagory. I thought that I could do it using the while statement then breaking before it loops. however the condition of the while statement is never being satisfied. This suggest to me that the sql statement is returning no values.

SQL of the database is below:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "Questions";
CREATE TABLE "Questions" ("QuestionID" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL , "Question" TEXT, "RightAnswer" TEXT, "WrongAnswer1" TEXT, "WrongAnswer2" TEXT, "Done" BOOL, "Catagory" TEXT, "Audio" INTEGER);
INSERT INTO "Questions" VALUES(1,'What is the BPM of this piece?','120 BPM','70 BPM','170 BPM','no','Rhythm',1);
INSERT INTO "Questions" VALUES(2,'How far apart are the 2 notes the bass guitar plays?','4 Semitones','1 Semitone','6 Tones','no','Pitch',1);
INSERT INTO "Questions" VALUES(3,'How is the organ Panned?','Left','Right','Centre','no','Pan',1);
INSERT INTO "Questions" VALUES(4,'What are the note values of the HiHat rhythms?','Semi quaver','Quaver','Crotchet','no','Rhythm',1);
INSERT INTO "Questions" VALUES(5,'The first chord played on the organ is...','Minor','Major','Atonal','no','Pitch',1);
INSERT INTO "Questions" VALUES(6,'How is the bass sound panned in this piece?','Right','Left','Center','no','Pan',2);
INSERT INTO "Questions" VALUES(7,'How is the lead synth panned in this piece?','Left','Right','Center','no','Pan',2);
INSERT INTO "Questions" VALUES(8,'The Kick Drum Rhythm In this can abe described as...','Four to the Floor','Off beat','Minor','no','Rhythm',2);
INSERT INTO "Questions" VALUES(9,'A clap sound can be heard on beat..','2 and 4','1 and 3','3','no','Rhythm',2);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "Results";
CREATE TABLE "Results" ("ResultID" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL , "QuestionRight" INTEGER, "TotalQuestions" INTEGER, "Catagory" TEXT);
```

So what i'm asking is:

1) is there a better way to read in only the first row that satisfies my sql statement?

2) is there a reason my current method isn't working?

Thanks for your help,

Ben

************* UPDATE *************

Here is where category is defined:

```
CatagoryLoaded = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"catagorysaved"];
switch (CatagoryLoaded) {
    case 1:
        CatagorySelected.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Pan!"];
        Catagory = @"pan";
        break;
    case 2:
        CatagorySelected.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Pitch!"];
         Catagory = @"pitch";
        break;
    case 3:
        CatagorySelected.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Rhythm!"];
        Catagory = @"rhythm"; 
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

************* UPDATE 2*************

I changed it to Limit 1 as you suggested and am now getting `thread1: signal SIGABRT`

```
if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    const char *query_stmt = "SELECT * FROM Questions WHERE Done='no' AND Catagory='%@' LIMIT 1", Catagory;

    int check = (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL));
    NSLog(@"%i",check);


    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {


            questionID = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
            questionString = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
            rightAnswerString = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];
            wrong1AnswerString = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3)];
            wrong2AnswerString = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 4)];
            audioInteger = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 5)];


        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }
    sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

************* UPDATE *************
looks like the statement is leaving it as `'%@'` instead of what ever is stored in category, any idea why?

Below is a link to a screen shot showing variables just before SIGABRT crash. (won't let me post the image directly as i am new to the site)

http://puu.sh/hkOxf/8c05b9489b.png

Comment: You never bind in a value for category.

Comment: What do you mean by this? ( I am new to IOS development).

Comment: The `, Catagory` does not do what you think it does. You need to use `NSString stringWithFormat`.

Comment: Thanks for the advise but could you write out the full line of code as i don't really understand. thanks

Comment: Used `NSString *query_string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT QuestionID, Question, RightAnswer,WrongAnswer1, WrongAnswer2, Audio FROM Questions WHERE Done='no' AND Catagory='%@'", Catagory];
        const char *query_stmt = [query_string UTF8String];` and it work thanks for the advice :)

Answer (score 1):

My only guess is that your "Category" variable is not a valid one. Other than that, the SQL statement looks good. I don't recall if SQLite is case sensitive but it wouldn't hurt to put Done and Questions and stuff in the proper case.

Also, for performance reasons, you can always add a "Limit 1" to the end of your SQL statement to get the first row. Or simply change it from a WHILE to an IF instead, so it only runs once, however, I recommend doing using the LIMIT syntax.

```
NSString *query_stmt = [NSString stringWithFormat:"SELECT * FROM Questions WHERE Done='no' AND Catagory='%@' LIMIT 1", Catagory];
```

Comment: Have added the code to my question where I define 'catagory'

Comment: I don't think the column names in SQLite are case sensitive but the values are. Your Category values need to match the case of the values in your DB. For example: "Rhythm" not "rhythm".... it's crazy to get down voted for this...

Comment: Your answer was originally down voted because it didn't answer the question and the posted code was wrong. The code is now fixed (though it may help to show the OP how to get the `char *` from the `NSString`).

Comment: I could understand if the code was wrong (wasn't familiar with the "const char *" syntax) but I don't believe I wasn't trying to help answer his question. It's very discouraging when any attempt at helping people gets downvoted, which seems to happen quite a bit.